# VBA to create word template from excel data

Tags: excel, vba

I have Excel VBA which will open the pre defined word template and will map the Name, address and other information based on bookmarks. I have macro which is currently does for the data in column A2. I want to insert loop so that I can pick and run automatically for all the Names in column A. Please advice how to use loop function.

```
.Selection.range(“A2”).copy
.selection Go to what:= -1, name:=“Namelocation”
.Selection.pastespecial
```

This code goes on with diff range and bookmark location

Comment: Your code has several problems. Selection doesn't (normally) take a . in front. The range A2 of a selection is NOT the same as the cell A2. The selection in the second line seems to be referring to the selection in Word not Excel - you need to distinguish them.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the response. Pleas find the below my code below. i want this code to be executed for all the value in column A using loop. please help

Comment: 'Documents.Add "C:\Users\Desktop\Temp.dotx"
         Range("F2").Copy
        .Selection.Goto What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="Dateloc"
        .Selection.PasteSpecial
        
         Range("B2").Copy
        .Selection.Goto What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="Nameloc"
        .Selection.PasteSpecial
        
        Range("e2").Copy
        .Selection.Goto What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="Addloc"
        .Selection.PasteSpecial'